# Calculating cell size of DEM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator, saga, cell-size

I am using the following raster calculation to create a topogrpahic wetness index in QGIS.

```
TWI/CTI = ln(a / (tan (beta))
```

where;

```
a=Upland contributing area: [(flow accumulation + 1 ) * (cellsize)]
beta=slope in radians.
```

I have calcualted the slope and upland contributing area successfully. However, I don't know the cell size of my DEM. I am fairly new to GIS, so this is likely a dumb question, but how do I find the cell size of my DEM? I downloaded it from a government website. It is the Canadian Digitial Elevation model (https://open.canada.ca/data/en/dataset/7f245e4d-76c2-4caa-951a-45d1d2051333?activity_id=b9b143a0-447d-4a1d-9f13-8d5f4dc0fa33)

Answer (score 1):

Open `Properties` of your raster layer (context menu: right click on the raster layer in the layer panel). In the `Information` tab, you find all the information - see screenshot 2 below.

To change pixel size, you can use [Raster alignement](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-alignment) or simply export the raster and change the resolution (and the CRS, if need be):

*Screenshot 1, export dialog window:*
[image]

*Screenshot 2, layer properties, indicating pixel size:*
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I have found the pixel size. However, is there a way to convert this to a single cell size value for the calculation above?

Comment: See updated answer